# Using entries from other kivy classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am a beginner in Language and I am trying to make a simple guessing game and I would like to know how I use the data entered in the Players Class in the Start_p1 Class. I want the name typed in the TextInput of the Players Class, to appear in the Label Text: of the Start_p1 Class.

Arquivo .py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Home(Screen):
    def next(self):
        self.manager.current = "players"

class Players(Screen): 
    def start(self):
        self.manager.current = 'st1' 


class Start_p1(Screen):
    def runn(self):
        self.manager.current = 'st2'


class Start_p2(Screen):

    def back(self):
        self.manager.current = 'st1'

class Finish(Screen): pass

class Myapp(App):
    sm = None

    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(Home(name = 'home'))
        self.sm.add_widget(Players(name = 'players'))
        self.sm.add_widget(Start_p1(name = 'st1'))
        self.sm.add_widget(Start_p2(name = 'st2'))
        self.sm.add_widget(Finish(name = 'finish'))
        self.sm.current = 'home'
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Myapp().run()
```

Arquivo.kv

```
#: import utils kivy.utils


<Home>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#2169af')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            text: 'Iniciar'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            size_hint: 0.2, .1
            background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#13447d')
            on_release: root.next()

        Button:
            text: 'Configurações'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
            size_hint: 0.2, .1
            background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#13447d')

<Players>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#2169af')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            pos: 0, 270
            text: 'JOGADORES'

        Label:
            pos: 0, 150
            text: 'Informe o nome do 1° Jogador:'
            TextInput:
                id: txtt
                pos: 270, 400
                size: 250, 30
                multiline: False

        Label:
            pos: 0, -20
            text: 'Informe o nome do 2° Jogador:'
            TextInput:
                id: txt
                pos: 270, 230
                size: 250, 30
                multiline: False

        Button:
            text: 'Iniciar'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .2}
            size_hint: 0.2, .1
            background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#13447d')
            on_release: root.start()

<Start_p1>:
    Players:
        id: players
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#2169af')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label: 
            text:
```

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a bit tricky. One would expect that you can use:

```
Label:
    text: app.sm.get_screen('players').ids.txt.text
```

That will technically work, but it won't set up the automatic update if the `text` of the `TextInput` changes. A careful reading the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#relation-between-values-and-properties) explains why, and suggests a work around. Using the suggestion from the documentation, you can do something like this:

```
Label:
    players_screen: app.sm.get_screen('players')
    text: self.players_screen.ids.txt.text
```

This produces the desired result with automatic updates.